# Getting a nil value while fetching Twilio access token

Tags: ios, swift, twilio

I'm trying to setup Twilio Programmable Chat in my iOS app and when I try to fetch access token it's returning a Nil. I'm using the same function calls which are provided in the swift sample app.

This is the function which is trying to fetch access token which is present inside a dictionary

```
func fetchToken(params:[String:String], completion:@escaping (NSDictionary, NSError?) -> Void) {
 
    if let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Keys", ofType:"plist"),
        let dictionary = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile:filePath) as? [String: AnyObject],
        let tokenRequestUrl = dictionary["TokenRequestUrl"] as? String {
        print(tokenRequestUrl)
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: tokenRequestUrl)!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        let postString = self.postDataFrom(params: params)
        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }
            
            if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {
                completion(NSDictionary(), NSError(domain: "TWILIO", code: 1000, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "Incorrect return code for token request."]))
                return
            }
            
            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! [String:Any]
                print("json = \(json)")
                completion(json as NSDictionary, error as NSError?)
            } catch let error as NSError {
                completion(NSDictionary(), error)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
    else {
        let userInfo = [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : "TokenRequestUrl Key is missing"]
        let error = NSError(domain: "app", code: 404, userInfo: userInfo)
        
        completion(NSDictionary(), error)
    }
}
```

The print `json` command is not getting executed, but when I tried printing `Data` before `try` it returns 2730 bytes. Hence a `null` is getting passed as dictionary and I'm eventually getting `nil` when I try to fetch access token.

#### Update:

I just tried printing the Data as string. HTML code is being passed inside `Data` object

Comment: What does your server respond with when you request the token?

Comment: I can see `200 OK ` on the console when I request for token

Comment: Can you request the token from the URL using a web browser? Or curl? What does that show?

Comment: I did try that, it opens Starter Kit Environment Setup page

Comment: So, this is probably your problem then. You need to make sure your server is properly returning a token, not a setup page. Can you update your question with more information on what you are using to produce the token?

Comment: So I just tried running the server on a different system. The browser returns a JSON with token. But the access token is still nil when I run it on Xcode and `print("json = \(json)")` is not getting executed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146743/discussion-between-aark-and-philnash).

Comment: @philnash It's working now. I made a mistake with the url. I called `http://ngrok/token` instead of `http://ngrok/token.php` . I need a clarification though. Is it mandatory to use PHP server for iOS?

Comment: It's absolutely not mandatory to use PHP to generate the token, but you do need to build a server of some sort to generate the tokens. There is [documentation on creating chat access tokens in various languages here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/access-tokens#code-creating-an-access-token-chat).